# Acces Denied IE8 on upload submit javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm get "access is denied" on IE8, (Chrome,Firefox IE>8 works), when javascript execute the submit:

```
    var iframe = this._createIframe(id);
    var form = this._createForm(iframe, params);
    ...
    ...
    form.submit(); //Access denied IE8
```

Anybody knows the solution bypass?

Comment: You haven't including anything useful here at all, so I can only guess that you are also programmatically clicking the file input element, which is causing IE to choke on the programmatic form submit.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you triggering the click??

You can't trigger the click via JS, IE denieds the acces.